# How to unit test an Azure Function against Dataverse?

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-dynamics, dataverse

I'm a developer with .net background and I'm new to the Dataverse / PowerPlatform ecosystem. I need to dev and test an Azure Function but not sure how to do it. I did found [this post in the official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/testing-tools-server) about tools for server side, but not sure how to do the same for client-side applications like Azure Functions.

Any guidelines?

Comment: Azure Functions are server-side applications. Not client-side

Answer (score -1):

*As suggested by @Markus Meyer, Azure functions are server-side applications. Not client-side applications*

*You can have a complete information and tutorial regarding Azure function in this Azure functions [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/).*